# Flow Charts and State Machines

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, infovis

Specifically I am looking at the JavaScript libraries; [JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit](http://philogb.github.io/jit/index.html), and [D3](http://d3js.org/) to draw flow charts and state machines.

Both of these offer plenty of ways to visualize data. However none of the examples seem to meet the requirements below (especially for flow chart).

To be clear I mean these.

**Flow chart**

[image: Flow Chart]

(Sourced from: http://philosophy.hku.hk/think/strategy/chart.php)

- Have branches with a single start and end point.
- Labels on nodes and branches.
- Have a logical flow layout (e.g. not nodes randomly positioned).
- Shapes aren't really important.

**State Machine**

[image: Finite State Machine]

(Sourced from: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/systems/fsm-156381.html)

- Labels on nodes and branches.
- Shapes aren't really important.

Would either of these libraries be able to meet my requirements?

Are my requirements even an appropriate use of those libraries?

Cheers,

Comment: [dagre-d3](https://github.com/cpettitt/dagre-d3/wiki) perhaps?

Comment: Not sure why this is receiving close votes. This isn't a recommendation or list question. It's a specific question about the specific capabilities of specific frameworks, for which there will be yes/no answers.

Comment: I have rephrased the question, and removed some extraneous detail. Hopefully I will avoid the 5th close vote!

Comment: d3 allows you to draw anything you like, so in that sense it's bound to be suitable. You'd have to do much of the work yourself though via bespoke code.

Comment: flowchart.js maybe http://adrai.github.io/flowchart.js/?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the end went with [dagre-d3](https://github.com/cpettitt/dagre-d3/wiki) which is able to do everything I needed.

Comment: I'm very impressed by this library. The only thing that disappointments me is the bundles size. All of lodash is included unfortunately. And v4 of D3 is being used yet all of that lib is imported. Wish only the needed modules were pulled in.

Answer (score 0):

You can also give a chance to [mxGraph](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/)

An example of mxGraph is [draw.io](https://www.draw.io/)