# Graph library Javascript

Tags: javascript, graph, draw

I need to do some graphs and so far I've been using fmsdesigner to be able to draw them, now I need to turn for example a NFA to a DFA, and I already did the code to transform it but now I have to draw it and it's quite a hassle so I was wondering if there's any library that would take care of that part for me? stuff like the node position, the link angle and stuff like that since the one I've been using requires me to calculate all that for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great comparison of [Javascript libraries](http://www.jsgraphs.com/) out there.

For non-free options, check out [JointJs](http://resources.jointjs.com/demos/fsa). It has a module specifically for graphing FSAs.

[Dagre D3](https://github.com/cpettitt/dagre-d3/wiki) also looks like a winner.

See [Flow Charts and State Machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30828501/flow-charts-and-state-machines).

Answer (score 1):

[Chart JS](http://www.chartjs.org/) is really easy and beautiful to use :-)

Answer (score 0):

For most sources of data, [d3](https://d3js.org/) is quite good